# Evaluate the given integral along the indicated closed contour $\oint_C\frac{sinz}{(z^2)+(\pi)^2}dz; |z-2i|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Evaluate the given integral along the indicated closed contour $\oint_C\frac{sinz}{(z^2)+(\pi)^2}dz; |z-2i|=2$

This should be solve by using Cauchy's formula but i couldnt find.( z=$\pi$i is in C)

This is my solution way:

$\oint_C\frac{(sinz)/(z+(\pi)i)}{z-(\pi)i}dz$

If i say f(z)=$\frac{sinz}{z+(\pi)i}$

My answer will be $2\pi$i *f '($\pi$i)
But i couldnt find f'($\pi$i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula is:
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz,$$
so taking $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z+\pi i}$:
$$\frac{\sin(\pi i)}{2\pi i}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{z-\pi i}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{\sin(z)/(z+\pi i)}{z-\pi i}dz,$$
and hence your integral is equal to $\sin(\pi i)$ - no derivatives necessary.

Comment: My bad. I tought it will be derivative. Thank you for your answer.